# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Gouvernante und Kindermädchen?

Tags: meaning, difference

When I was young, my parents put me in the care of a German-American woman. That's why I'm here. (Deshalb bin ich hier.)

How is such a woman referred to, as a "governess," or "nanny?" Or some thing else? What is the difference? (Or isn't there any?)

Wie nennt man eine  solche Frau: Gouvernante, Kindermädchen oder anders?

Was ist der Unterschied, oder gibt es keinen?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Der gängige deutsche Begriff ist definitiv *[Kindermädchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinderm%C3%A4dchen)* oder, wenn es um nur um Tagesbetreuung geht, während die Eltern arbeiten sind, modern *[Tagesmutter](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagesmutter)*. Kindermädchen und Gouvernante sind *Angestellte im Haushalt der Eltern*; die Tagesmutter arbeitet in ihrem eigenen Haushalt, *die Kinder werden zu ihr gebracht*.

*Gouvernante* ist veraltet und wird im Alltag nicht mehr verwendet. Aus [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouvernante):

> Gouvernante - eine veraltete Bezeichnung für Hauslehrerin oder Erzieherin. Dieser Beruf stellte über lange Zeit für Frauen eine der wenigen Möglichkeiten dar, einen standesgemäßen Beruf auszuüben. Er wurde vor allem von Frauen aus der gebildeten Mittelschicht ergriffen, die nicht verheiratet waren.

Für kurzzeitige Betreuung ohne erzieherische Aufgaben (z.B. Beaufsichtigung des Kindes für einen Abend) verwenden wir den Anglizismus *[Babysitter](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babysitter)*. Kindermädchen, Tagesmutter und (früher) Gouvernante waren demgegenüber feste Bezugspersonen für das Kind und für die Steuerung der Entwicklung des Kindes mitverantwortlich.

Junge Frauen oder Männer - meistens Frauen - die für einen längeren Zeitraum (z.B. ein halbes oder ganzes Jahr) ins Ausland gehen, um in einer Familie Kinder zu betreuuen und dabei die fremde Sprache und Kultur kennenzulernen, werden [Au-Pair](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au-Pair) genannt.

Comment: Wer Johanna Spyris *"Heidi"* gelesen oder gesehen hat, kann sich Fräulein Rottenmeier als Beispiel für eine Gouvernante vor Augen führen.

Comment: Denn war sie eine Gouvernante.

Comment: @splattne: I want to ask a question about the difference between the "Etch" and the "Aedige" (if any). But fear it may be too sensitive. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Tom I'm almost completely ignorant of Südtirol's history, but would say if in doubt, ask away. The SE sites have a history of being able to discuss even sensitive issues in remarkable neutrality - I'm sure the german.SE site will want to continue that tradition. (Still, interested to hear what @splattne has to say)

Comment: @Tom_Au It's simple: *Etsch* is the German name of the river and *Adige* is the Italian name. Latin: *Athesis*

Comment: @Tom_Au Maybe you mean South Tyrol's Italian name which is "Alto Adige" (instead of "Sudtirolo"). Fascists came up with the name in the 1920s, so there are people who reject it, but it's the official Italian name and commonly accepted.

Comment: @splattne: So "Etsch" and "Adige" are the same? And they both refer to a river in the South Tyrol? And sometimes "Alto Adige" refers to the South Tyrol? Vielen danke.

Comment: @Tom_Au exactly. Also see my previous comment just before yours.

Comment: @Pekka's answer: I would say that "Kindermädchen" is a bit old-fashioned, too. IMHO it refers to a member of the staff living in your house, which is obviously quite uncommon today. Also, I think the main difference between "Kindermädchen" and "Gouvernante" is that latter one has an educational purpose. The first one is rather similar to a "nanny".

Comment: @ladybug Agree, Mary Poppins is a _Gouvernante_, not a _Kindermädchen_ (though some people nowadays probably would prefer to call her an _Erzieherin_).

Comment: Apart from language issues: I had a nanny, but not a "gouvernante". Nannies don't teach, while "gouvernantes" do. And these days, people say "Nanny" (because of the popular TV series, the English word has become well known), "Kinderfrau" or "Kindermädchen" or, depending on the function, "Tagesmutter".

Answer (score 11):

There was a clear difference. The *Gouvernante* was *always* a teacher. She nearly always taught manners and French and often many other things like sketch, stitching and music. [This paper by Mrs. Gresshöner](http://www.grin.com/de/e-book/108246/die-gouvernante-im-buergerlichen-haushalt-des-19-jahrhunderts) cites *Die Gouvernante* by Hardach-Pinke as follows:

> ,,Mütter und weibliche Verwandte konnten zwar in der Regel kostenlos Unterricht in Lesen, Religion und Handarbeiten erteilen, aber nur selten in Fremdsprachen, Musik, Geschichte und Geographie".

From the memoirs of the Bronte sisters you will see how difficult it was for them to get jobs as governances without a good knowledge of French. In fact, mastery of the French language was so essential, that at one point the word *Französin* came to mean *governess*.  Gresshöner explains:

> Seit dem 18. Jahrhundert wurden deutsche Gouvernanten häufig ,,Erzieherinnen" genannt - zu polemischen Zwecken. Sollten doch die als tüchtig bekannten einheimischen Gouvernanten die als oberflächlich verrufenen Französinnen verdrängen. 1789 arbeiteten in Deutschland so viele französische Frauen als Gouvernanten, dass die eigentliche Nationalitätenbezeichnung ,,Französin" als Berufsbezeichnung genutzt wurde. Bis ins frühe 19. Jahrhundert hielt die starke Nachfrage nach französischen Erzieherinnen an, die bis dahin ein wahres Monopol im deutschen Erziehungswesen eingenommen hatten.

There were also regional differences. In Germany, standardised training was offered, when British families still regarded class background and skills as solely important. [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouvernante#Ausbildung_der_Gouvernante) cites *Die Gouvernante* by Hardach-Pinke on the claim that:

> In Großbritannien nahmen erst 1848 das Queen’s College und das Bedford College ihre Arbeit als Ausbildungsstätten für Gouvernanten auf.

For Germany, on the other hand, referencing the same work, it claims:

> In Deutschland gab es bereits gegen Ende des 18. Jahrhunderts Forderungen nach der Einrichtung von Ausbildungsstätten von Erzieherinnen. Zu den Frauen, die sich unter anderem dafür einsetzten, zählen Amalia Holst, Betty Gleim und Elisabeth Bernhardi.

In some countries there existed different types of governances, like the *preparatory governess* that taught writing to little boys and girls. I am not aware of such distinctions in Germany.

Some people preferred to use *Gouvernante* for the educators of girls and *Hauslehrer* for the teachers of males. Wikipedia provides the following details based, again, on Hardach-Pinke:

> August Hermann Niemeyer beschrieb [...] 1796 in seinem Ratgeber für Hofmeister, dass die Gouvernante für die Erziehung der Mädchen zuständig sei, der Hauslehrer dagegen für die der Jungen. Beide können stundenweise die Zöglinge des anderen unterrichten. Beschäftigt ein Haushalt nur eine Gouvernante, dann übernahm sie die Erziehung der Jungen bis etwa zu deren achtem Lebensjahr.

The *Kindermädchen* had a more general role. She frequently did housework and often didn't speak French. *Kindermädchen* who did where known as *Bonne* in Germany.

However, the following citation from  *The Victorian governess* by K. Hughes suggests there might have been some overlap in poorer British families:

> Those widowers who had failed to marry again, and who had no female relative living nearby, were obliged to pay a woman to live en Familie to carry out the duties formerly performed by their wives. It was these men, […] who use the governess much as single women had been used for centuries – as a way of plugging a gap in the household’s available personell. In these modest homes the governess was not simply a teacher, but a housekeeper, stepmother and even parlourmaid rolled into one.

Note, however, how even this text contrasts the situation with the traditional role as a teacher!

While many *Gouvernanten* lived with the family and participated at least in those activities their trainees attended, there was also the *Tagesgouvernante*, who did not live with the family.

Answer (score 1):

We are multi-kulti in Germany now. My neighbour has a "nanny". Otherwise known as "Beate ihr Kinderfrau".

Edit: I ought to point out that "Beate ihr Kinderfrau" is South German dialect and not standard German.

Comment: One might however discuss if the tendency of using US American words for a growing host of things is actually a symptom of multiculturalism, or rather a symptom of growing US American cultural hegemony and world-wide mono-culturalism. See also the nauseating habit of calling things that look delicious "yummy", even in German speaking regions of the world, or the habit of adding "IMHO" to whatever utterance of opinion. (When I see "IMHO", I hear an old man with cancer-ridden lungs coughing. Unpleasant.)

Comment: I would suggest pointing out that „Beate Ihr Kinderfrau“ is not „Standarddeutsch“. :) Many people here are learning the language and trying to pass exams.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Nanny is a British English word.

Comment: "Beate ihre Kinderfrau" could be used in the Ruhr area too. The (fictional) anecdote is that the Schalke stadium was supposed to be called "Dem Ernst Kuzorra seine Frau ihr Stadion".